# WebGL: drawArrays: attribs not setup correctly

Tags: html, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

Here's my vertex shader:

```
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
    attribute float type;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
      vColor = aVertexColor;
      if(type > 0.0) {

      } else {

      }
    }
```

What I want to do is pretty simple, just capture a float value named `type` and use it for logic operates.

The problem is, when I try to use it in Javascript, the error comes:

```
shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "type");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);


WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attribs not setup correctly main.js:253
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attribs not setup correctly main.js:267
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: attribs not setup correctly
```

The output of `getAttribLocation` is meaningful, all of them are equal greater than 0.

**================= UPDATE ===================**

Here's my whole project code:

https://gist.github.com/royguo/5873503

Explanation:

- index.html Shaders script are here.
- main.js    Start the WebGL application and draw scene.
- shaders.js Load shaders and bind attributes.
- buffers.js Init vertex and color buffers.
- utils.js   Common used utils.

Comment: Did you try using a float instead of vec2? By the way, using branches that depend on attributes inside your shader is a major performance hit, I always try to use a mathematical statement instead of branches.

Comment: @Marius, Thanks! I changed vec2 to float, but the problem is still there. `INVALID_OPERATION` ...

Comment: Your code looks correct, the fault has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @Marius, I don't know but it seems to be something is wrong with **attribs**.

Comment: @Marius, My variable is `float`, can I use `enableVertexAttribArray` ?

Comment: please add some code about your buffer setup (gl.bufferData)

Comment: I've managed to get the code you have posted working on my own, so your problem must be with some part of the code that you have not showed us. If you could give us the rest of your code we could probably help you out.

Comment: Thanks so much @Anton, I've update my question to add a Gist of my code.

Comment: @Marius, I've update the question to add my code, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/antonpantev/5874176) to a gist with the files I updated to get the `type` attribute working.

If you search for `//ADDED CODE` you should be able to view every change I had to make to get it working.

In addition to enabling the `objectTypeAttribute` you have to create an array buffer for each object you are drawing:

```
  triangleObjectTypeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleObjectTypeBuffer);
  objectTypes = [
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(objectTypes), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  triangleObjectTypeBuffer.itemSize = 1;
  triangleObjectTypeBuffer.numItems = 3;
```

And bind that array buffer for each object before you draw the object:

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleObjectTypeBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.objectTypeAttribute, triangleObjectTypeBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

You probably already tried this and accidentally went wrong somewhere along the way.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense for me now ! Just for confirmation, Does the `objectType` array item number must the same as vertex item number ?

Comment: Just one more question ... Can I get every pixel's position in fragment shader ? Thanks :D